Question about proof of Lemma 10.10 in "Lectures on von Neumann algebras"
Consider the following fragment from the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras" by Stratila and Zsido (see section 10.10 p308):

Why can we assume that the support projection $s(\psi)=1$, i.e. that $\psi$ is faithful?

Maybe you can restrict to $s(\psi) Ms(\psi)$ (which is a unital von Neumann algebra with unit $s(\psi)$) and, since $s(\varphi)\leq s(\psi)$ then $s(\varphi)\in s(\psi) Ms(\psi)$.

Thanks. This worked.
